# SAPUI5 Icon in Image Control

Tags: image, fonts, sapui5

We are using `sap.ui.commons.Image` control in our project and we need to set a font icon as the source.

The `sap.ui.commons.Image` is used in multiple places and are used in composite controls as well. However, we need to use icon-fonts as the source to the control. We could set SVG/PNG to the source and it works fine. However, we need to use `icon-font`.

Can anyone help?

```
<c:Image src='sap-icon://add' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You will either have to download the icon and store it in your project
Or use a control that has an **icon** property for example a button or icon tab